# apply a function on each row with different arguments

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I have data table like below DT,

```
         col1     col2    col3    col4    col5
1:          1       2       3        4      5
2:          4       5       6        8      9
3:          3       4       4        5      5
4:          4       3       5        3      3
5:          4        5       6        6      67
```

I want to count unique values in certain columns for each row (for each row I want to use different columns for counting unique)

How do I achieve this in minimum number of steps possible? The table is huge so running for loop is out of the question.

I am looking for a solution like

```
 DT[ , count_unique:= apply(DT[ , cols, with = F], 1, function(x) { length(unique(x)) })]
```

But this will fail, since "cols" will need to take different columns for each row.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at `mapply`which allows you to supply multiple arguments to your function?

Comment: You _might_ be better off reshaping your data to long format. But I cannot comment how exactly to do it since your expected output is unclear.

Comment: please provide the desired output as I don't understand what exactly it is you want, if you just want to count the number of unique items per row this is simply `apply(DT, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))` ; but how do the number of columns to consider for the calculation differ rowwise??

Comment: struggling to follow what the intended result is supposed to look like. Can you add what the intended result would look like for the sample data set?

Comment: Do you have another dataset which shows the columns to be used for each row or is it based on random sampling?

Comment: You'll need to clarify where `cols` comes from...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easiest to do with matrices, which have a matrix subset operation (from which incidentally the `data.table` join syntax is inspired from).

Let's say this is your data:

```
m = matrix(c(1:4, 1,3,2,2, 1,2,3,3), ncol = 3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    3    2
#[3,]    3    2    3
#[4,]    4    2    3
```

And let's say you want to count unique values for all columns for rows 1 and 2, and for first and last columns only for rows 3 and 4. The way you can represent this is as follows:

```
cols = matrix(c(1,1, 1,2, 1,3,
                2,1, 2,2, 2,3,
                3,1, 3,3,
                4,1, 4,3), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    2
# [3,]    1    3
# [4,]    2    1
# [5,]    2    2
# [6,]    2    3
# [7,]    3    1
# [8,]    3    3
# [9,]    4    1
#[10,]    4    3
```

The result you want is then easy to compute:

```
tapply(m[cols], cols[,1], function(x) length(unique(x)))
#1 2 3 4 
#1 2 1 2
```